# What does $\omega{(1)}\cdot O(logN)$ mean?

Tags: asymptotics

What does $\omega{(1)}$ mean as a factor?
In some papers, there exists some asymptotic analysis which comprises a product of multiple Landau notation like $\omega(1)\cdot O(logN)$.
In this example, what is the meaning of the additional factor $\omega(1)?$

Comment: Do you realise what does $\omega(f(n))$ means?

Comment: No I already know the definition of small omega notation.

Comment: Use the placeholder semantics to get rid of the abuse of notation. (If people use that in research papers, I'm not sure they know what they're doing. :/)

Answer (score 6):

It presumably means a product of the form $f(N)\,g(N)$, where $f(N)\in\omega(1)$ and $g(N) \in O(\log n)$.

However, that's a very strange thing to write, since *every* well-behaved function $h$ can be written in this way. If $h\in\omega(1)$, write it as $h(N)\cdot1$, which is valid, since $1\in O(\log N)$; if $h\in O(1)$, write it was $N\cdot (h(N)/N)$.

Comment: Is "well-behaved" here to justify your consideration of only two cases exclusively? Is that what it means?

Comment: @Omar I wanted to rule out annoying cases like $$h(x) = \begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\text{ is even}\\x^2&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$